# Get value of variable outside the function

Tags: javascript, scope, global-variables

I'm trying to get value of variable outside the function but I can't able to do so. Kindly give answers

```
<script>
    var lati;
    var lngi;   
    function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) 
    {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } 
      initialize();
    }
    function showPosition(position) 
    {
      lati=position.coords.latitude;
      lngi=position.coords.longitude;  
    }
    alert(lati);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not get your value, because you are not calling `getLocation()` function. Because you are not calling it, it nevers change the value of `lati` and then it display it's default value which is `undefined`.

```js
// ------------------------ FUNCTIONS TO SIMULATE
const navigator = {
  geolocation: {
    getCurrentPosition: (func) => {
      func({
        coords: {
          latitude: '0.5125',
          longitude: '51.545',
        },
      });
    },
  },
};

function initialize() {

}
// ------------------------ FUNCTIONS TO SIMULATE


var lati;
var lngi;

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  }

  initialize();
}

function showPosition(position) {
  lati = position.coords.latitude;
  lngi = position.coords.longitude;
}

getLocation();

alert(lati);
```

Comment: dude you use hard values how i can get the user location. cuz my last code do it but now i can't.

Comment: I don't get your point. My whole answer and hard values are just here to show you that it'll work if you call `getLocation()` function

Answer (score 0):

In the snipped provided in the question, `showPosition()` is never called and, therefore, cannot modify the variable `lati`. If you call `showPosition()` before `alert(lati)`, it should work.

Comment: i know but `showPosistion()` is get parameter and i don't have any.

Comment: I see, so then you need to call `getLocation()` before the `alert`. It then calls `showPosition(position)` with the required parameter.